# Buffalo NAS not showing in NasNavigator 2.84

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, nas

OK Heres one I am hoping someone can help me with.  I have two Buffalo NAS, a LS-WXL and an LS-WVL.  They have static IP addresses and plug into the router I am using, a Cisco 877. I am running Windows 8.1, all latest updates installed.

Previously, I was using a Netgear DGN2200v3 modem / router.  The NAS' were visible in my "Networks" list, 5 shares were mapped and both LinkStations showed up in NasNavigator 2.84.

Since swapping to the Cisco 877, whilst I can ping the NAS and the shares are accessible via the mapping (and the computer "wakes" the NAS on startup), the NAS' no longer show up in my "Networks" list and they do not show in NasNavigator 2.84.

I stress I **CAN** access them and they are mapped ... just not showing up.

Network Discovery is "on" on my Laptop ... anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  For anyone else who may have a similar issue, the way I got around it was to uninstall NasNavi 2.84, reboot, then re-install NasNavi 2.84.  Then everything works quite happily.

Comment: sadly didn't work for me, but thanks for taking the time to answer your own question